# Custom Excel VBA function returning error in some cases, not in other

Tags: vba, excel

My function is supposed to check a cell for a string, and then return that string if its present, and return an empty string if it's not. The first two parts are working fine--it checks, and it returns the string it it's present, but if the string isn't present, it returns an error (#value). What's happening?

```
Function Keyword(cell As Range, word As String)
  'checks given cell for keyword, returns keyword if present
  If (WorksheetFunction.IsNumber(WorksheetFunction.Search(word, cell.Range("A1"), 1))) Then
     Keyword = word + ", "
  Else: Keyword = ""
  'returns empty string if not present
  End If
End Function
```

Call it like this: =Keyword(H2,"LED")

Comment: When you get #Value's form the function what values are you passing it?

Comment: I pass the function a cell and a string, and it looks for the string in the cell. If the string is there, it returns the cell, but if it's not, it returns an error--I need it to return an empty string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the value you are looking for isn't found, you'll get run-time errors, and your function will fail. Easier to use `InStr` to search for the value:

```
If Instr(1, cell.Range("A1").Value, word, vbTextCompare) <> 0 Then Keyword = word & ", "
```

Comment: Why *cell.Range("A1").Value* rather than *cell(1).Value* ??

Comment: @Gary'sStudent Just because that's what was in the original. :) Makes no difference.

Comment: That stops the error, but it doesn't return the keyword

Comment: Apologies - I just realised the order of the parameters was wrong and revised the answer!